# recover files encyrpted in bitlocker

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I activated bitlocker with my drive and when it was encrypting something the power was suddenly interrupted. When I returned to my drive and entered the unlock password, The bitlocker wizard is not responding! Tried to wait for an hour but to no avail. Is there any way I can access the files again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this MSKB Article explains [How to use the **BitLocker Repair Tool** to help recover data from an encrypted volume](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928201).

*although referring for Winows Vista and Server 2008, this should be valid for Windows 7 too.*