# How to recover files from formatted BitLocker encrypted drive

Tags: bitlocker

I've used ThinkVantage Secure Data Disposal tool aiming to erase a HDD 7 times but I stopped it once i've started (in 2 secs). The HDD is Win7 OS with Bitlocker encrypted. When I started the laptop again, no OS is found. I got the 48-digit Bitlocker recovery key on hand. May i ask how I can recover the partitions or data from the drive?

Comment: Have you followed the advice in the accept answer for this question: http://superuser.com/questions/75773/recover-files-encyrpted-in-bitlocker?rq=1?